# Extrude bone from extruded bone

Tags: modeling, bones

I'm making a model for a person, and I need to do the upper/lower arm. I already extruded a bone from the spine for the upper arm, but when I extrude a bone from the upper arm, It also extrudes a bone from the spine. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bone which head is selected will be extruded. While selecting the already extruded bone, the bone from which you have extruded remained selected.

```
How to:
In Edit Mode:
Deselect everything 
Select bone head, which you want to extrude.
Extrude
Deselect everything
and so forth...
```